# Subsetting using element names in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a very basic question. Let's suppose we have a atomic vector wherein two elements (or more than two elements) have same name, like:

```
x <- c(a = 1, b = 2, b = 3, c = 4)
```

In R elements can be subset using names, like

```
x["a"]
```

It returns element name `a` in `x`.

But if I write:

```
x["b"]
```

It return only first element of `b` ie 2 only.

I just wanted to know why R does not return both 2 and 3 (ie all elements matching with `b`) ?

I already know I can subset all elements matching with `b` using

```
x[names(x) %in% "b"]
```

I wanted to know why default behaviour is just to return first matching element of `b`?

Comment: Probably so the type and length of the output i predictable. It's really better practice to avoid this situation though.